# String to Integer array conversion

Tags: java

I need to add values into an int array.

```
    int[] placeHolders[];
```

Now i do not know the size of the elements to add into this array. I add it while i have input. I want to know  how can i convert my string output values into int array repeatedly.

Input: 23.45.1.34

I am using string tokenize on . to get tokens

```
Value = Integer.parseInt(strtokObject.nextElement().toString());
```

I am using above line to add int to single int value but if i need to add int elements to array just like push in vector (C++ STL) i am unable to do.

Comment: in fact you can't push elements in java arrays, use Lists/ArrayLists instead. Also by using string.split(".") you'll get an array of strings representing your numbers

Comment: Use an ArrayList rather than a normal array decliration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your input string is `input`.

So you can do something like this:

```
String[] inputStrs = input.split("\\.");
```

and

```
//Do a while loop
placeholder[i] = Integer.ParseIne(inputStrs[i]);
```

Comment: Make sure you escape that '.' (`\\.`), otherwise you'll be splitting on EVERY character (`String.split()` takes a regular expression).

Answer (score 5):

```
String str = "23.45.1.34";
String sarr = str.split("\\.");
int[] result = new int[sarr.length];
for (int i = 0;  i < sarr.length;  i++) {
    result[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Comment: Using: 

     ArrayList<Integer> placeHolders;
int value = Integer.parseInt(strtokObject.nextElement().toString());
    cageObject.placeHolders.add(value);


Still getting errorsException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

When you don't know the size of a data set to be stored in an array, you should use an implementation of `java.util.List<E>` such as `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> placeHolderList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int value = Integer.parseInt(strtokObject.nextElement().toString());
placeHolderList.add(value); // adds the int to the underlying array
```

You can then use List#toArray to convert your list into an array if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `myString.split("\\.")` to return a `String[]`, create an equal size `int[]`, then parse each String to an int rather than use a tokenizer. Also you could know the size of `placeHolders` by counting '.'s in the string (e.g., `myString.replaceAll("[^\\.]", "").length()`) (obviously add one to that number).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList<Integer>` which is similar to vector in c++.
add to it using `aList.add(num);`

if you want an array you can at the end use the `toArray` method.

```
Integer[] arr = aList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```